# Shouldn't I need to call .emit when I create custom EventEmitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

```
var myEvent = new EventEmitter(); 
myEvent.on("someEvent", messg => {   console.log(messg); });
myEvent.emit("someEvent", "Hello its my first custom event");
```

So I created an EventEmitter Object and custom event. I am adding my custom event named `"someEvent"` to the myEvent object then call `.emit` function to see the result of inner arrow function.

```
var fs = require("fs");

var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/readme.txt", {
  highWaterMark: 50
});
//data event added
myReadStream.on("data", chunk => {
  console.log("new chunk received:");
  console.log(chunk);
});
```

However, in this streaming example, I did not call `.emit` function but this arrow function is called. How could that happen, I guess that `"data"` event is built in the event?

Comment: You don't call emit with `fs.createReadStream()` because only it knows when it's read new data and it emits the event to let you know. You simply listen for the event.

Comment: I understood from the code what you said, The question is that is "data" built-in event so that I can listen? like btn.on( "click",...) ?? @MarkMeyer

Comment: Yes, it's a documented part of Node streams: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node.js a stream is a sub-class of an `EventEmitter` and it emits its own events.  So, the stream itself is the one call `.emit()`.  You just listen to the events you are interested in and the stream will emit them when appropriate.

> However in this streaming example I did not call .emit function but this arrow function is called. How could that happen, I guess that "data" event is built in event?

Yes, the `data` event is a built-in event that is part of what the stream does.  As soon as you register a listener for the `data` event, it starts the stream flowing and then whenever it has data to read, it will emit the `data` event.  That's a built-in behavior of a `stream.Readable` which is what `fs.createReadStream()` creates.

You can see one of the places that the `data` event is emitted in the readable source [code here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L280).

```
function addChunk(stream, state, chunk, addToFront) {
  if (state.flowing && state.length === 0 && !state.sync) {
    state.awaitDrain = 0;
    stream.emit('data', chunk);
  } else {
    // update the buffer info.
    state.length += state.objectMode ? 1 : chunk.length;
    if (addToFront)
      state.buffer.unshift(chunk);
    else
      state.buffer.push(chunk);

    if (state.needReadable)
      emitReadable(stream);
  }
  maybeReadMore(stream, state);
}
```

You can see all the events that the `stream.Readable` object emits in the [doc here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's built in.

Once you use the [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) API, a [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) is created and the `data` event is called when a listener is bound to it.

From the docs:

> The 'data' event is emitted whenever the stream is relinquishing ownership of a chunk of data to a consumer. This may occur whenever the stream is switched in flowing mode by calling readable.pipe(), readable.resume(), or by attaching a listener callback to the 'data' event.